# Mysql could not be started because unknown variable 'log-syslog=1'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Platform System： WSL（ubuntu 18.04）.

when installed mysql-server 8.0 sucess， i try to start mysql. But it's fail to start.Then checked the error.log.

```
2019-02-26T03:13:51.609895Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'log-syslog=1'.
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: [log_syslog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_syslog) Deprecated in 8.0.2, removed in 8.0.13.

Comment: When you have a systemd like 18.04 and journalctl with it, you don't need the ugly hacks provided mysqld_safe in init scripts to get a syslog capture.

Answer (score 14):

I've run into the same problem as yourself and found this question while looking for solution. Eventually I found the culprit.

You will find that `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf` contains 2 rows:

```
[mysqld_safe]
syslog
```

The only thing you have to do is remove syslog. I just commented it out:

```
[mysqld_safe]
#syslog
```

And now it works.
It is weird that it comes preconfigured like that since it is deprecated/removed (I did a clean install of v8.0.15).

Comment: This file was still lying around from the official Ubuntu package of MySQL 5.  I ran `sudo apt purge mysql-server-5.7` to get rid of it.  *WARNING*: This asks if you want to remove your databases.  Ensure you say No.

Comment: *WARNING*: `sudo apt purge mysql-server-5.7` deleted /var/log/mysql .  Ensure you back up this directory before running this command.

Comment: Thx, it helped me solve the problem :)

Comment: Had to re-create /var/log/mysql folder as Alastair mentioned, plus give it `mysql` owner and group permissions

Answer (score 0):

From the Changelog:

> ----- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> The system variables have been removed that previously configured
>   error logging to the system log (the Event Log on Windows, and syslog
>   on Unix and Unix-like systems). Where appropriate, the removed system
>   variables were replaced with new system variables managed by the
>   log_sink_syseventlog error log component. The following table shows
>   the old and new variable names.
>
> Old System Variable   New System Variable log_syslog_facility
>     [syseventlog.facility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_syseventlog.facility)
>   log_syslog_include_pid
>     [syseventlog.include_pid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_syseventlog.include_pid)
>   log_syslog_tag
>     [syseventlog.tag](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_syseventlog.tag)
>   log_syslog    None Important
>
> Installations that used the old system variable names must update
>   their configuration to use the new variable names. For more
>   information, see [Error Logging to the System
>   Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-syslog.html).
>
> References: See also: Bug #27534089.